# Where to reset SecurityContextHolder when testing Spring MVC application with MockMVC and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mockmvc

I want to test Spring MVC web application.
My application use JWT authentification with Spring Security, parsing JWT token by custom JWT authentification provider called by PreAuthentificationFilter and set result to SecurityContextHolder.
I use mockMvc to test it, and configure it as below

```java
this.mvc  = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
    .apply(springSecurity())
    .build();
```

In my test method, I call target controller 2 time.
First time's result is as expected, but second time is not.
That's because authentification in SecurityContextHolder of first time is still remaining in second time.
I try to reset SecurityContextHolder in many way, such as reset it in test method, or in another custom Spring Security Filter, and so on,  but it still remaining.
Would you tell me why it so and where to reset it.

Thank a lot.

Comment: How are you setting the context? In most cases, you'd either use `@WithMockUser` (or similar) or pass the JWT as part of the MockMvc request.

Comment: I make custom class which extends  AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter. It set SecurityContextHolder in its doFilter method.

Comment: Why are you not using the built-in Spring Security JWT support? And note that all the library implementations clear the security context in a `finally` block.